# Make desktop icon box opaque on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, icons, desktop, desktop-customization

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate SP1. I have an elaborate desktop background image, within which most desktop icons become visually obscured. See image below:

[image]

Is there a way of making the icons with their associated text box have a non-transparent, solid-colour background, something to the effect shown below:

[image]

Comment: I use a plain theme and then in the details use black borders. Works.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm having trouble finding the details option for selecting black borders.

Comment: There is a third party tool mentioned in this post: https://superuser.com/questions/390025/how-can-i-change-font-and-color-of-the-captions-under-the-icons-on-the-desktop that I think comes closest to achieving what I require. But I was wondering if there was a native way of doing it.

Comment: I posted a native solution to a nice clear Windows 7 desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Use Windows Personalization settings (right click on Windows 7 desktop). Choose a neutral theme (blue) to start.

Then in the Personalization windows, in Windows Color, use Windows Classic.

This will yield Windows with black and some white borders.

Desktop icons will be borderless (where I said black that was Window Borders) and the Desktop icons show up very clearly.

If you wish to add a picture, choose one that works with a clear setup. Some pictures damage the ability to read the screen.

You might wish to use the Screensaver to show pictures and leave your working screen more plain.  After all, work means Apps, not looking at pictures.

[image: Windows 7 easy to use desktop]

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, while I try out the assorted options within "Window Color", especially those that are font, size and colour related. I'm trying to at least get the icon captions as contrastingly visible as possible, without going overboard. I'm also trying out some of the "Visual Effects" options within "Advanced System Settings". I'm surprised there is no registry value that can render desktop icon and caption containers in a non-translucent/transparent manner? As a last option (and one that I probably won't opt for) I now know there exists "Iconoid".